# Which planet contains the seat of the new Republic government?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In *The Force Awakens*, a new government, called the Republic, has come to power, and is providing support and assistance to the Resistance. At one point, we see what appears to be the Senate building and the seat of power of the Republic, which

> the First Order completely destroys, along with it's 4 moons/other planets.

Do we know the identity of the planet where the new Republic government is being run from?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the [wiki](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hosnian_Prime),

> Hosnian Prime is the Capital of the New Republic, and the whole Hosnian System is what we see destroyed in the movie. Their was  "chatter on D'Qar when they're planning the Starkiller raid that it was the 'Hosnian System' that was destroyed."

This is based on both reference in movie, as well as a new book [The Force Awakens Visual Dictonary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_The_Visual_Dictionary)

Comment: I find it maddeningly annoying that this is never explained in the movie.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh yeah it would have solved my question if i would have known the capital moved...

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh Yeah, if there was any explanation at all in the movie of what that planet was or why they were destroying it, I entirely missed it. Seemed like a random weapons test.

Comment: Considering one of the complaints about the prequels were that there was too much exposition and boring political talk I suppose JJ decided to err on the side of less of that stuff. Those of us who are into more background info will eventually find it in the new books and comics.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh, just before the Hosnian system is destroyed there is a monologue (by Hux I believe) about how they would be destroying the seat of the Republic, which was why i thought it was Coruscant until the mention of Hosnian later on in the film

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh There was a scene early in the movie where Leia talks to her attaché arguing the Resistance's case before the New Republic that gives more information, but it was removed from the final running of the film before release. The movie will make a *lot* more since when all the deleted scenes (~30 minutes!) are added, sort of as a "complete" cut, when the DVD/Blu-Ray come out. Though Abrams won't likely release an extended/director's cut, since he's on record as not being a fan of those.

Answer (score 9):

Also, to add to existing answers, TFA Visual Dictionary clarifies that Hosnian Prime is not the **permanent** seat of the New Republic.

The capital is moved from place to place in accordance with votes.

Because Democracy!

Comment: Sounds expensive. Like, mind-numblingly expensive.

Comment: @Ellesedil just think of it like the Olympics or the world cup, it moves every set years to whoever the committee selects, and that planet builds a massive stadi--I mean senate building

Comment: @Ellesedil Sounds like EU moving from Brussels to Strasbourg once a month...

Answer (score 5):

Luckily, [another question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111089/how-did-characters-see-this-event-happen-in-the-force-awakens) provides the names of the planets.  [Takodana](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Takodana) is the planet our intrepid heroes were on, and from there they watched

> the destruction of [Hosnian Prime](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hosnian_Prime).

So presumably Coruscant is safe.

Answer (score 3):

> The system destroyed was the Hosnian system (it is mentioned by name in a later scene). It was indeed the current seat of the New Republic senate.