# How close was Starkiller Base to the New Republic capital?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

The sequence in Star Wars Episode VII: The Force Awakens seems to imply that it took only seconds for the energy beam to reach the New Republic capital from Starkiller Base.

How close was the planet to the Bosnian system? (And did it really only take seconds for to reach the capital?)

Comment: The beam traveled through hyperspace. That's why everyone in the galaxy can see it and how it travels at superluminal speeds

Comment: @Valorum well shit I never thought of that. And here the Empire was 30 years earlier  lugging a whole *"small moon"* through hyperspace so they could shoot stuff, and getting it blown up because it couldn't orbit a planet fast enough.

Comment: Partial dupe of [How is Starkiller Base's beam visible from Takodana in The Force Awakens?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111089/how-is-starkiller-bases-beam-visible-from-takodana-in-the-force-awakens)

Answer (score 5):

Starkiller Base was located in the Unknown Regions to the galactic North-West. Hosnian Prime is located close to the Galactic Core, slightly to the galactic South-East.

Given that the Skyriver Galaxy is [approximately 100,000 light-years across](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_galaxy#cite_note-Moving_Target-3) (and assuming 
the Starkiller Base didn't move before firing), that means that the two planets are **approximately 40,000 light-years away from each other.**

[image]

As mentioned in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/112846/20774), the beam was traveling through hyperspace at super-luminal speeds, allowing it to travel from a to b without having to crawl through realspace.