# What did the Starkiller kill?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In *The Force Awakens* we see a powerful weapon capable of immense destruction. When it's activated, we see

> five or so planets and a sun that are

enemies of the First Order destroyed.

Is there a verified list of the target**s** *by name*?

### I'm *not* asking for merely the most publicized target.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Was this planet destroyed?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111088/was-this-planet-destroyed)

Comment: @RogueJedi I've clarified that I'm asking about *all* targets, not just one (or a collective name). I didn't see an answer with that information on the other question, but I have updated mine to take out the tangent-question which *was* answered there.

Comment: Fair warning: if you vote to close this question, it shall become more powerful than you can possibly imagine. Failing that, I'll undupehammer it because the OP clearly explained it was NOT a dupe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of this moment, no. There is no official, published list.

We won't know until more information is published from an official source. The [official novelization](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_%28novel%29) mentions the Hosnian system ten times, but only ever refers to Hosnian Prime's neighbors as "the Hosnian System's other worlds" or "the Hosnian worlds". It does name Korr Sella as the Resistance officer staring at the bright light in the sky in Republic City on Hosnian Prime for a brief moment,  before Hosnian Prime's destruction, but that's the only clue.

Unfortunately the Visual Dictionary does not mention what the other worlds  (and whether they are planets or just moons) of the Hosnian System are aside from Hosnian Prime. It shows an updated Galaxy Map (though it only shows a smattering of worlds), but doesn't mention whether any of the worlds near Hosnian Prime (such as Corellia) are *in* the Hosnian system or just near it (my guess is that they're not, considering *system* tends to refer to solar system).

[image]

Comment: I hope the VD provides some insights. I know that some names, such as [Lor San Tekka's](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lor_San_Tekka), were revealed in [other books](http://www.amazon.com/Wars%C2%AE-Journey-Force-Awakens-Find%C2%AE/dp/1503701956)

Comment: I guess the asker wasn't asking for this, but simply "The capital of the republic" would have cleared things up for me. Took a couple questions and answers for that to become clear. Would have made the movie make more sense if I had picked that up while watching it.

Comment: @DCShannon I remember one of the baddies calling it "The capital...", but I had *just* watched Episode II, and the capital was still Coruscant. Like everyone else, I didn't know it was moved, and I'm also a bit annoyed that we don't have actual names for the other planets. (For all we know, they were nameless because they were worthless, like uninhabited Mars).

Comment: @CreationEdge Updated the post, the Visual Dictionary doesn't name the other worlds.

Comment: @CreationEdge FWIW, the New Republic voted to move from Coruscant as a major show of solidarity with the dissident voices that started the downfall to the Senate in the Old Republic; sort of a symbolic way of saying "we're serious about this". They also voted to rotate "the capital" between a collection of various member worlds. It is possible that the five destroyed worlds were the ones between which the capital rotated over time.

Comment: It seems obvious to me that the Hosnian System would be a planet orbitted by several moons and not several planets. Its about the only way they could all be visible in the same sky without telescopes.

Comment: @Octopus What evidence makes it obvious to you beyond the fact that you can see the other worlds in the night sky? As I'm sure you're aware, Star Wars is a fictional universe with many fictional physical properties, and we can see other planets in our night sky in real life, too.

Answer (score 1):

As per the accepted answer, the others appear to be unnamed.

While there isn't an official canon answer, it would be handy to have placeholder names until there is. "Those other planets destroyed with Hosnain Prime" is a bit of a mouthful.

Since it looks like they were all in the same system, and the designator "prime" implies more with similar names, [it would make sense](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=518123) to call them "Hosnian Secunde", "Hosnian Tertie", "Hosnian Quarte", etc. At least until we hear something official different.

Comment: Since Starkiller blew up *all* the planets in the system, I think people would probably just say "the Hosnian System" when talking about its annihilation.

Comment: @TylerH - You're probably right. There might be some call in-universe one day for a character to refer to one (perhaps a character hails from there), but since all we know about them now is that they were destroyed together, there's no real need for us to address individual ones by name.

Comment: @TylerH ...but one of the possible motivations for this question might have been a desire to have names anyway (perhaps for fan-fiction?), so I thought it worth addressing.