# What were the planets destroyed in "Star Wars: Episode VII: The Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

My question is pretty much the same as my title.

`"What were the planets destroyed in "Star Wars: Episode VII: The Force Awakens?"`

I ask as I felt the republic planets destroyed didn't really hold much weight in the film and not a lot of light was cast on their importance. E.g. There was no mention of it it by Leia or to Leia or around Leia. In the film Leia has a force reaction at the final event with Kylo Ren and Han Solo on the bridge however she doesn't seem to be grieving or even effected by "the great disturbance in the Force, as if millions of voices suddenly cried out in terror and were suddenly silenced".

It has been stated that save for Hosnian Prime the planets are unnamed. However can anyone speculate as to the importance of the other 4 destroyed planets and if they were not planets such as Naboo or prequel republic based planets.

Comment: I however am asking specifically what 5 planets are destroyed by star killer base?

Comment: @joshuatvernon The Wookieepedia page mentioned in the other answer describes them as "Hosnian Prime and all other astronomical bodies in the system." Are you sure they're all supposed to have names?

Comment: @MrLister I'm not sure I just wasn't sure if by the geological signs whether it can be suggested that the planets were noteworthy or of importance in the previous films or extended universe as they seemed to be very nonchalant about the destruction.

Comment: My question is very close to [What did the Starkiller kill?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111289/what-did-the-starkiller-kill)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The planets destroyed were [Hosnian Prime](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hosnian_Prime) and four other unnamed planets

Hosnian Prime was the Capital of the New Republic. Although population numbers are not mentioned it was likely heavily populated, as it is stated as having an Urban Terrain